# calling new intent from imageButton Created on listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-imagebutton

I have a listView with an imageButton. When i click on the imageButton, I am trying to call a method in the main class that will display a toast message. However, when i click on the button, i get an error saying:

```
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:94)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:240)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at com.flamesavor.reme.ReMe.setAlarm(ReMe.java:69)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at com.flamesavor.reme.resources.ListViewAdapter.setAlarm(ListViewAdapter.java:62)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at com.flamesavor.reme.resources.ListViewAdapter$1.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:49)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17343)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is my Arrayadapter where I have created the onClickListener. The listener calls a method in the adapter which then calls the setAlarm method in the Main Class (called 'ReMe').

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends android.widget.ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> reminders;
    private View reminder;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.reminders = objects;
    }


    //Change textcolor to black. Everything else remains same
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        //Set view to convertView if the there are already rows created
        reminder = convertView;

        if(reminder == null){
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            reminder = inflator.inflate(R.layout.reminder_list_layout, parent, false);
        }

        //Set imageButton actionListener
        ImageButton alarmButton = (ImageButton) reminder.findViewById(R.id.reminder_alarmnavigation);
        alarmButton.setTag(reminder);
        alarmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setAlarm((View) v.getTag());
            }
        });

        //Initialize and assign reminder title
        TextView reminder_title = (TextView) reminder.findViewById(R.id.reminder_title);
        reminder_title.setText(reminders.get(position));

        return reminder;
    }

    public void setAlarm(View view){
        ReMe reminder = new ReMe();
        reminder.setAlarm(view);

    }

}
```

Below is the method in the ReMe class:

```
public void setAlarm(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetReminder.class);
    TextView reminder_title  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reminder_title);

    Toast.makeText(ReMe.this, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //intent.putExtra("com.flamesavor.reme.reminderTitle", reminder_title.getText());
    //startActivity(intent);
}
```

Not sure where I am making a mistake. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is the modified code that tries to trigger an activity instead if creating a toast:

```
public void setAlarm(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SetReminder.class);
        TextView reminder_title  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reminder_title);       
        intent.putExtra("com.flamesavor.reme.reminderTitle", reminder_title.getText());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Below is the error log that i get. Not sure why this is happening:

```
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3562)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at com.flamesavor.reme.ReMe.setAlarm(ReMe.java:67)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at com.flamesavor.reme.resources.ListViewAdapter.setAlarm(ListViewAdapter.java:62)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at com.flamesavor.reme.resources.ListViewAdapter$1.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:49)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17343)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-18 22:53:06.381: E/AndroidRuntime(8706):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

=====================================================================================
Resolution (Edited):
Set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and called the new activity in the context of the view.

```
TextView reminder_title  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reminder_title);   
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), com.flamesavor.reme.SetReminder.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.flamesavor.reme.reminderTitle", reminder_title.getText());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: you have to use activity's context to show a toast

Comment: context you have to refer

Comment: Post `ReMe.java` and use `view.getContext()` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException 04-17 18:25:16.293:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
>   04-17 18:25:16.293: E/AndroidRuntime(9236):     at
>   android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:94)

`ReMe.java` is not a Activity class. `ReMe.this` does not refer to a valid context.

So change to

```
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29)

```
public final Context getContext ()

Added in API level 1
Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.

Returns
The view's Context.
```

Also change this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetReminder.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SetReminder.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the toast. Now I am trying to fire up the intent, but I am getting a similar error. I modified the intent as you mentioned above. Below is the modified ReMe.java method:


public void setAlarm(View view){
  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SetReminder.class);
  TextView reminder_title  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reminder_title);  
  intent.putExtra("com.flamesavor.reme.reminderTitle", reminder_title.getText());
  startActivity(intent);
 }

Comment: 04-17 21:32:18.268: E/AndroidRuntime(11571): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 21:32:18.268: E/AndroidRuntime(11571): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 21:32:18.268: E/AndroidRuntime(11571):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
04-17 21:32:18.268: E/AndroidRuntime(11571):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to format it in the comment section.

Comment: @flamesavor you can edit you post and post the same. Well its a NPE again. there is a caused by part in the stacktrace post it

Comment: hi, I have updated the question with the new code and error log. Really appreciate your help on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @flamesavor which line is line 67 in `ReMe.java`

Comment: It is the startActivity call. I think there is some problem with the intent I am trying to create. Not sure.

Comment: Hi, the issue got fixed. I called the startActivity in the context that i provided and set the New Task Flag.

Answer (score 0):

You use "this" as the first parameter of the Intent constructor, which indicate that the current class is your context, so use the same "this" as the first parameter of Toast.makeText

Comment: `this` is same as `ReMe.this` unless its inside a annonymous inner class. And `ReMe.this` is not a valid context in this case

Comment: It it is the same, the intent should not be created

Comment: that also should be changed to `view.getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

If `ReMe` class does not belongs to context then there is a problem, because you must have to specify context or Activity to show `Toast` in the app